# Cannot assign a non-static member function in clang Linux, but I can in Visual Studio Windows?

Tags: c++

I have a very simple class which returns a string:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    const char *GetString() const
    {
        return "bar";
    }
};
```

And I have a very simple class which holds a function pointer to GetString.

```
template < class classname >
struct ClassFunctionPointer
{
    typedef const char * ( classname::* StringReturner )( void ) const;
    StringReturner  stringReturnerFnPtr;
};
```

Then I have this code which compiles fine under Windows (Visual Studio), but does not under Linux (clang).

```
ClassFunctionPointer< Foo > fptrs;
fptrs.stringReturnerFnPtr = &(Foo::GetString);
```

The error under Linux is: `error: call to non-static member function without an object argument`.  I don't understand this error, because I am not making a function call.  I am just assigning the function's address to a function pointer.

It doesn't work if I perform a cast either:

```
ClassFunctionPointer< Foo > fptrs;
fptrs.stringReturnerFnPtr = reinterpret_cast< typename ClassFunctionPointer< Foo >::StringReturner >(&(Foo::GetString));
```

Comment: Error is about a call to a function: "_error: call to non-static member function without an object argument_", but I don't see any calls of said function, anywhere in your question. How are you calling it? Are you even calling it in your Windows example?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius That's a common diagnostic that assumes the intent was to call the function, but more often than not the intent was to produce a function pointer (and the programmer forgot the `&`). So the fact that the OP isn't calling the function is not really the point.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica After reading your comment: first thought was: But the asker didn't forget the `&`!, but then I noticed that the fact whether you compile as `&(Foo::GetString);`, and `&Foo::GetString;` makes a difference for GCC, and clang, while not making a difference to VC.. Good to know.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yeah that's the key component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This boils down to your use of parentheses. Let's produce a minimal testcase:

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar();
};

int main()
{
    &(Foo::bar);
}
```

You've indicated that Visual Studio accepts this. It shouldn't!

> [`[expr.unary.op/4]:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#4) **A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit `&` is used and its operand is a *qualified-id* not enclosed in parentheses.** *[ Note:* That is, the expression `&(qualified-id)`, where the *qualified-id* is enclosed in parentheses, does not form an expression of type “pointer to member”. Neither does `qualified-id`, because there is no implicit conversion from a *qualified-id* for a non-static member function to the type “pointer to member function” as there is from an lvalue of function type to the type “pointer to function” (`[conv.func]`). Nor is `&unqualified-id` a pointer to member, even within the scope of the *unqualified-id*'s class. *— end note ]*

I have no idea *why* this rule exists.

Regardless, every version of GCC that I've tried [rejects the code](https://godbolt.org/z/qevEYK):

> error: invalid use of non-static member function 'int Foo::bar()'

*This is a common diagnostic that signifies you've forgotten either `&` or `()`. Some versions of some compilers use a different, and way more confusing wording ("call to non-static member function without an object argument").*

[Clang agrees](https://godbolt.org/z/d-9uPP).

It's common for Visual Studio to be slightly over-lenient about such things.

Since you want your code to be portable and standard-compliant, go with the more usual:

```
&Foo::GetString
```

That is, **remove the parentheses**.

Comment: This was the solution!

Comment: @PhengleiKai Good innit!